# YII how to get data from another`s session?

Tags: yii

I need a UI to manage all app sessions. How could I retrive data from foreign sessions? I`m interested in getting data set by`setState` function during other users login.

I'm using CDbHttpSession for storing sessions in DB

Answer (score 2):

So, i found answer, but it isn`t good in my opinion. But maybe it will be helpfull for others. Yii stores data in session table using php built in session serialization method (it isn`t regular serialize function). And only way that i found to work with it is suggested on the php session_decode manual [page](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-decode.php) in the comments.